# How to list all shared folder and files only in Google Drive API?

Tags: php, google-drive-api

How can I list only the shared folders/files in Google Drive API?

I have this in my code;

```
$parameters['fields'] = 'files(id, name, modifiedTime, mimeType, parents, trashed, permissions, webViewLink, webContentLink, exportLinks), nextPageToken';
```

but when I try to add the Owners field, it's not showing who shared the folder/file.

Comment: I recently wrote a blog post and explained how to do this. https://faridmovsumov.medium.com/how-to-list-sub-and-shared-folders-by-using-google-drive-api-with-a-php-client-dc45db2c1f75

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal and your current situation as follows.

- You want to retrieve the list of shared folders and files you shared in your Google Drive.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis for PHP.
- You have already been able to get values from Google Drive using Drive API v3.

In this case, I thought that `shared` property of the file metadata can be used. But, unfortunately, in the current stage, it seems that there are no search query for directly retrieving such files. So, as a sample script, when the list of all folders and files that you shared in your Google Drive is retrieved, this property is checked. This point is reflected to a script of PHP, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client); // Please use your "$client".
$pageToken = '';
$list = [];
do{
    $res = $service->files->listFiles([
        'pageSize' => 1000,
        'fields' => 'nextPageToken,files(id,name,mimeType,shared)',  // or '*'
        'q' => "'me' in owners and trashed = false",
        'pageToken' => $pageToken
    ]);
    $files = $res -> getFiles();
    if (!empty($files)) {
        foreach ($files as $f) {
            if ($f -> getShared()) {
                array_push($list, $f -> getName());
            }
        }
    }
    $pageToken = $res -> getNextPageToken();
} while ($pageToken != "");
print($list);
```

- In this sample, the file and folder names are retrieved as a list in `$list`. When you want to retrieve other file metadata, for example, please modify `array_push($list, $f -> getName());` to `array_push($list, $f);`.
- When you use `*` as the value of `fields`, all file metadata is retrieved.

#### Note:

- If you want to retrieve the files shared from other users, you can also the following sample script.

  ```
    $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client); // Please use your "$client".
    $pageToken = '';
    $list = [];
    do{
        $res = $service->files->listFiles([
            'pageSize' => 1000,
            'fields' => 'nextPageToken,files(id,name,mimeType)',  // or '*'
            'q' => "sharedWithMe",
            'pageToken' => $pageToken
        ]);
        $files = $res -> getFiles();
        if (!empty($files)) {
            $list  = array_merge($list , $files);
        }
        $pageToken = $res -> getNextPageToken();
    } while ($pageToken != "");
    print($list);
  ```

#### References

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [Search for files and folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files)

Comment: Thank you sir for the detailed answer! Justs what I needed1 this : 'q' => "sharedWithMe" really do the trick for me i can't find that in the documentation. You rock! Can I also make a request? Can you post also how will I get the email who shared with me? Should I use getPermission function?

Comment: @Mon Padi Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. From your replying, I understood that `list` of `I list only the shared folders/files in Google Drive API` was the files of `sharedWithMe`. About your new question, I would like to support you. But unfortunately, I cannot understand about your new question. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about your new question, can I ask you about the detail of it? By this, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: Hello sir! My new question is how can it display the name of the owner in sharedwithme? Should I use getPermission function? Or just recommend something for me sir.

Comment: @Mon Padi Thank you for replying. From your replying, I understood that you wanted to retrieve the owner of the files of `sharedWithMe`. In this case, I think that you can achieve your new goal by including `owners` in `fields` like `'fields' => 'nextPageToken,files(id,name,mimeType,owners)'`.

Comment: Okay sir! Thank you again for the best answer! I can breathe again lol this problem have been stressing me this couple of days. Thanks again!

Comment: @Mon Padi Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could understand your question by your cooperation. Thank you, too.